# What will be the Yule’s Coefficient of Association?

Tags: statistics

This might be a  very basic question but I am not so familiar with Yule's Coefficient of Association. The below question appeared in a test which is as under

[image]

I have tried to solve the problem after reading some notes from various sites and came up with the below solution

Total adults(N) = 10000
Literate (A) = 1290
Unemployed (B) = 1390
Literate and unemployed(AB) = 820

Let X = Illiterate, Y = Employeed

The  2 X 2 contingency table will be

```
          A      X       Total
B        820    570      1390
Y        470    8140     8610
Total   1290    8710     10000
```

Yule's Coefficient of Association 
**( (AB)(XY) – (AY)(XB)  )  /  (  (AB)(XY) + (AY)(XB)  )**

```
= ( (820 * 8140) – (470 * 570 ) / (820 * 8140) + (470 * 570 ) )
= ( 6674800 – 267900 ) / ( 6674800 + 267900 )
= 6406900 / 6942700
=+ 0.9228
```

Comment : The association is positive between Literacy and UnEmployment

Is it correct?

Please assist.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE. Take a look at [How to ask a good question at Math.SE](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). To avoid downvotes and closing you should add your own efforts to the question, and tell us where you got stuck. Our aim is to improve your mathematical skills (not to do your homework).

Comment: @drhab, Sir, I have edited my question by putting the attempt that I made to solve the problem. All I want is to verify my attempt and if it is wrong please help me to figure out.

Comment: May I know why i have been downvoted?

Comment: You were downvoted (also by me) because any attempt lacked, making it impossible to verify it. That is a legitimate reason here to downvote and/or vote for closing. I expect you to understand that. It has been withdrawn now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your contingency table looks sensible based on the information you have

Looking at that, your comment that *the association is positive between Literacy and Unemployment* looks correct

[Wikipedia's article on Yule’s Y, also known as the coefficient of colligation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_colligation)  gives a slightly different expression $$Y = \frac{\sqrt{ad}-\sqrt{bc}}{\sqrt{ad}+\sqrt{bc}}$$ which may give about $0.6662$ with your data

but I think your value of 0.9228 is Yule's Q as a *Yule coefficient of association* and looks sensible